# Is this a full binary tree?

Tags: binary-tree

Here's the binary tree in question. The leaves are a, b, c, d and the edges are labelled 0 or 1.

```
    .
   / \
  a   .
     / \
    b   .
       / \
      c   d
```

It seems to me that it is a full binary tree, as every node is either a leaf or has two child nodes, however I have this feeling that we were told it is not a full binary tree. If not, why is it not?

If a node has a child that is a leaf, does that not count as a child node?

Comment: [This page](http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-complete-binary-tree-and-vs-full-binary-tree) will solve all your doubts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing a perfect binary tree with a full binary tree. A perfect binary tree is a full binary tree with all leaf nodes at the same level. So yes, the picture is a full binary tree.

A leaf is defined as a node without a child node.
Thus, a full binary tree is a binary tree in which each node has either zero or two children.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) helps very well with definitions. Make sure you check it out.

Comment: I was going to say that it is not balanced. But thanks for a new definition. You learn something everyday.

Comment: Balanced is another story. It means depth difference between right and left child of each node is at most one.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "So yes, the picture is a **perfect** binary tree"?

Comment: No. The picture doesn't satisfy the condition I said. A perfect binary tree of depth N will have (2^N - 1) nodes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a tree with each node has zero or two children, it is binary tree.